# How to find $\bf F$ in minimizing $\log\left|{\bf A}\left({\bf G}{\bf F}{\bf G}^H+{\bf B}\right)^{-1}+{\bf I}\right|$?

Tags: logarithms, convex-optimization, determinant

I am recently faced with the following problem

\begin{array}\
\begin{align}
 \mathop {\min }\limits_{\bf F} \quad & \log\left|{\bf A}\left({\bf G}{\bf F}{\bf G}^H+{\bf B}\right)^{-1}+{\bf I}\right| \tag{1.a}\\
 \text{s.t.} \quad &  {\text {tr}}({\bf F}) \leq P, \tag{1.b}\\
 &  {\bf F} \succeq {\bf 0}, \tag{1.c}
\end{align}
\end{array}
where $\bf A$ is a positive semi-definite matrix, $\bf B$ is a positive definite matrix, $P>0$, and all matrices are $N \times N$ dimensional square.
This is a convex problem (please refer to another question for the convexity proof
[Convexity proof of log-determinant $\log\left|{\bf A}\left({\bf G}{\bf X}{\bf G}^H+{\bf B}\right)^{-1}+{\bf I}_N\right|$ with respect to $\bf X$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4191855/convexity-proof-of-log-determinant-log-left-bf-a-left-bf-g-bf-x-bf-g)).
Hence, I hope to find the closed-form solution to $\bf F$ or at least find a way which can obtain the optimal solution quickly.

To solve problem (1), I referred to the water-filling method, which is usually applied to solve the following problem
\begin{array}\
\begin{align}
 \mathop {\max }\limits_{\bf F} \quad & \log\left|{\bf G}{\bf F}{\bf G}^H+{\bf I}\right| \tag{2.a}\\
 \text{s.t.} \quad &  {\text {tr}}({\bf F}) \leq P, \tag{2.b}\\
 &  {\bf F} \succeq {\bf 0}. \tag{2.c}
\end{align}
\end{array}
Denote the singular value decomposition of $\bf G$ by ${\bf W} {\bf V} {\bf T}^H$.
Objective function (2.a) can then be written as
\begin{align}
\log\left|{\bf G}{\bf F}{\bf G}^H+{\bf I}\right| & = \log\left|{\bf W} {\bf V} {\bf T}^H {\bf F}{\bf T} {\bf V}^H {\bf W}^H+{\bf I}\right|\\
& =\log\left| {\bf V} {\hat {\bf F}} {\bf V}^H +{\bf I}\right|,\tag{3}
\end{align}
where ${\hat {\bf F}} = {\bf T}^H {\bf F}{\bf T}$.
Problem (2) can then be solved by using water-filling.

However, this method does not work in solving problem (1).
In particular, using eigenvalue decomposition, we can get ${\bf A} + {\bf B} = {\bf U}_1 {\bf D}_1 {\bf U}_1^H$ and ${\bf B} = {\bf U}_2 {\bf D}_2 {\bf U}_2^H$.
Problem (1) is then equivalent to minimizing
\begin{align}
& \log\left|{\bf G}{\bf F}{\bf G}^H+{\bf A} + {\bf B}\right|- \log\left|{\bf A} + {\bf B}\right| -\log\left|{\bf G}{\bf F}{\bf G}^H + {\bf B}\right| + \log\left| {\bf B}\right|\\
=& \log\left|{\bar{\bf G}}{\bf F}{\bar{\bf G}}^H + {\bf I}\right|-\log\left|{\hat{\bf G}}{\bf F}{\hat{\bf G}}^H + {\bf I}\right|, \tag{4}
\end{align}
where ${\bar{\bf G}} = {\bf D}_1^{-\frac{1}{2}} {\bf U}_1^H {\bf G}$ and ${\hat{\bf G}} = {\bf D}_2^{-\frac{1}{2}} {\bf U}_2^H {\bf G}$.
Denote the singular value decomposition of ${\bar{\bf G}}$ and ${\hat{\bf G}}$ by ${\bf W}_1 {\bf V}_1 {\bf T}_1^H$ and ${\bf W}_2 {\bf V}_2 {\bf T}_2^H$, respectively.
Since ${\bf T}_1 \neq {\bf T}_2$, we cannot get a ${\hat {\bf F}}$ as in (3).

I would be very appreciated if someone could provide some relevant hints or references to solve problem (1).